# Making all cells in a column links from the values within the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of cells in a Google Spreadsheet with values such as:

```
512
2123
2342
3532
```

What I would like to do is convert all these into a hyperlink and keep the value as the link text:

http://www.example.com/id/{value}

...where {value} is the value of the cell. I know the format of a hyperlink in a Google spreadsheet but I don't want to do this manually every time I put in a number. I want a simple process that when I add a new row the contents of this column is turned into a link with the value I input.

I tried this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.example.com/id/",A1);A1)
```

But I get:

> error: Circular dependency detected

Comment: @Jacob, the answer should not be added as a tag. Tags are added to find questions: Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is no longer reproducible as of November 18, 2023. Please bear in mind that posts should be self-contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your results. As a matter of fact, it worked perfectly.

[image]

What you tried to do is most probably the following:

In `A1` you typed in `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.example.com/id/",A1);A1)` and this yields an error of coarse.

### Update

If you really want to get the result in `A1`, then you need to use a script.

### Code

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "create URL", functionName: "createURL"}];
  ss.addMenu("URL", menu);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var activeRange = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(activeRange.getColumn() == 1) { 
    if(e.value != "") { 
      activeRange.setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/id/'+e.value+'","'+e.value+'")');
    }
  }
}

function createURL() {
  var aCell = ss.getActiveCell(), value = aCell.getValue();
  aCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/id/'+value+'","'+value+'")');  
}
```

### Explained:

The `e.value` will retrieve the cells value (only applicable a cell). The `setValue()` will add the concatenated string into the `getActiveRange()`. All is only executed when `e.value` contains something and the active range is in column A.

I've created an extra menu option as well, to be able access the script this way.

### Example:

I've created an example file for you: **[onEdit URL builder](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFpxOHlhZ05tT3F5Q0Vfc01zbXV0eEE&usp=sharing)**
Add this script via Tools>Script editor, into the script editor. Press the "bug" button and you can use the script.

Comment: Your right I did type it in A1. I want the link to appear in the same cell. So in my A column every time I type a number it will turn that into a link with the number appended to the url. Does that make sense?

Comment: @KirillFuchs will it always be the same URL?

Comment: Yes, it will just need the value appended to it. So whatever value I enter it would be url/value

Comment: @KirillFuchs I've added a script solution, that will yield the URL when entering a value in `A1`.

Comment: Thank you, I was messing around with a script and mine was turning out to be some weird mess. This is a-lot simpler. PS: updated your script to output the HYPERLINK function :). Thank you again.

Comment: @KirillFuchs Yeah, I saw it. It is better like this. Why don't you edit my answer?

Comment: One more thing, can you give me a bonus answer, and make that into a function I can run as well? The sheet I currently have already has lines with numbers in the column. :)

Comment: @KirillFuchs See revised answer and example file. Good luck !!

Answer (score 2):

I modified Jacob's answer to be a little more flexible. Just copy & paste this script. A menu will get created with a macro "Convert Selected Cells To URLs". Says it all. Now select which cells, in the same column, you want converted to urls and click macro.

Script

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {

  var menu = [{name: "Convert Selected Cells To URLs", functionName: "createURL"}];
  ss.addMenu("My Macros", menu);

}

function createURL() {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  if(range.getNumColumns() == 1) { 

    var numRows = range.getNumRows();

    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      var value = range.getCell(i,1).getValue();
      range.getCell(i,1).setValue('=HYPERLINK("'+value+'","'+value+'")');
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it and no script needed. You just need to use another sheet.

See the updated sheet mentioned above for the working example.

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.example.com/check-out.html?value1=",roundup('sheet2'!A1),"&value2=",$B30,"&value3",$C30),roundup('sheet2'!A1))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't this what the OP tried in the question?

Comment: Yeah but than if the other sheet is deleted, so are the links.